# Is there a way to get last insert group of data in database? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to fetch numbers or groups of data, how can I achieve this?

To visualize, here is an image

[image]

How can I fetch the highlighted one, instead of the none highlighted data.

Right now my problem is that I can only fetch data that are not highlighted as you can see in the image.

Here is my Model and its query I used.

> As you can see I hard coded the date so I can fetch the data that I want. But still how can I modify it so I will not use a hard coded data.

```
public function view_results($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('results');
    $this->db->where('student_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('post_id', $this->input->post('postId'));
    $this->db->where('date_answered', '2020-03-26 19:27:18');
    $this->db->group_by('question');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose You need do add into table an unique attempt ID for each attempting to solve a test. Then you will select all rows based on this attempt ID.

Comment: Galecki - an `ID `that is incremental? Is that what you suggest?

Comment: No, unique ID of attempt. It's not incremental. I mean PHP funcion `time()` or similar.

Comment: Galecki - Hello, I am not really sure what that means. can you give me an example please? or an input? to make it more clear? thank you sir

Comment: Add to your table column `exam_id`. When you insert data add additional info representing exam ID. This will allow you to select all rows for specified exam ID. Sorry, I don't know application architecture so I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Group by question and also by date_answered so you will get what you want.

`$this->db->group_by('question');
 $this->db->group_by('date_answered')`